# C# refactoring dropdown generation with generics MVC4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I have an MVC4 project with admin pages that have lots of drop down lists.  The first iteration of my drop down generation is in a class (DropDownEngine) that generates lists of DropDownItems based on some parameters passed in.

```
public class DropDownItem
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

As an example, here is one of the DropDownEngine functions:

```
public List<DropDownItem> GetDivisionsDropDown(bool isActive, bool hasPrompt)
{
    // Get active divisions from the database.
    List<Division> divList = DivisionDAO.FindAll(new GetActiveDivisions(isActive)).ToList();

    var dropDown = new List<DropDownItem>();
    if (hasPrompt)
    {
       dropDown.Add(new DropDownItem() { ID = 0, Description = "Select one", Name = "SelectOne", IsActive = false });
    }

    foreach (var div in divList)
    {
       DropDownItem di = new DropDownItem { ID = div.ID, Description = div.Description, Name = div.Name, IsActive = div.IsActive };
       dropDown.Add(di);
    }

    return dropDown;
}
```

As you can imagine, we have a different method for each list of entities, all producing a List, either with or without a prompt item.  I want to refactor this so that I can send the already queried List into my DropDownEngine and just generate the dropdown, but I am not sure how to write the interface for my generic List.

Since all of the Entities have the same attributes (ID, Description, Name, IsActive), I  think this should be doable, but how do I write the appropriate interface for my entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface IDropDownItem
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class Division : IDropDownItem
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public List<DropDownItem> GetDropDown<T>(bool isActive, bool hasPrompt, IEnumerable<T> input) where T : IDropDownItem
{
    var dropDown = new List<DropDownItem>();
    if (hasPrompt)
    {
       dropDown.Add(new DropDownItem() { ID = 0, Description = "Select one", Name = "SelectOne", IsActive = false });
    }

    foreach (var item in input)
    {
       DropDownItem di = new DropDownItem { ID = item.ID, Description = item.Description, Name = item.Name, IsActive = item.IsActive };
       dropDown.Add(di);
    }

    return dropDown;
}
```

Something like the above if I understand the question correctly.

Personally I'd write an extension method like so:

```
public static IList<DropDownItem> ToDropDown<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, bool isActive, bool hasPrompt) where T : IDropDownItem
{
    //Same as before
    ...
}
```

You could also make some other optimisations (e.g. returning an MVC SelectList object, creating an HtmlHelper extension method which overrides the inbuilt DropDownListFor and leverages the OptionLabel argument instead of using the has prompt method you use).

Comment: Thanks, rashleighp.  The other optimizations look like they have some merit, too, but I am not sure I will do them in the first refactor- it's a bit more than I can bite off in the time I've got.  Thanks so much for the help.